# The represetaion of vector in numpy: is the return of np.array() a row vector?

Tags: numpy

I am new to numpy, I guess the return of np.array() is a row vector, Because the dot product between two vectors is commutative, is my guess right? Any respone is grateful.

```
vx = np.array([1, 2])
vw = np.array([3, 5])
np.dot(vx, vw)
np.dot(vw, vx)
```

Answer (score 1):

The arrays are 1d ('vectors', not row/column vectors).

First paragraph from `dot` docuentation:

> For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D
>   arrays to inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation). For
>   N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of `a` and
>   the second-to-last of `b`

So you are getting the inner product, which is commutative.

```
In [118]: vx = np.array([1, 2])
In [119]: vx.shape
Out[119]: (2,)
```

`dot` returns a scalar:

```
In [120]: np.dot(vx,vx)
Out[120]: 5
```

For a 2d 'row vector', shape matters.  `dot` is matrix multiplication, and last dim as to match 2nd to the last, e.g. 2 matches with 2.

```
In [121]: vx2 = np.array([[1,2]])
In [122]: vx2.shape
Out[122]: (1, 2)
In [123]: np.dot(vx2, vx2)
...
ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
In [124]: np.dot(vx2, vx2.T)
Out[124]: array([[5]])
```

In this case the result is 2d (1,1).